# How to malloc correctly for a struct and certain variables?

Tags: c, malloc, valgrind

I'm trying to malloc for Racer but I keep getting errors in Valgrind can someone help me understand why it is not the way I have it?

Valgrind tells me the errors are at lines 49, 50, and 57... I marked them with arrows.

Here's my racer.c code:

```
#define _BSD_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

long waitTime = DEFAULT_WAIT;
pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

// Does the setup work for all racers at the start of the program.
void initRacers( long milliseconds ){
    clear();
    if (milliseconds != 0){
        waitTime = milliseconds;
    }
    pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL);
    srand(time(NULL));
}

// Creates a new racer.
Racer *makeRacer( char *name, int position ){
    int remain;
    int sizeOfRear = 0;
    char *frontSide = "o>";
    char *rearSide = "~0=";
    char *middleOfCar;

    int lengthOfName = strlen(name);
    int lengthOfRearSide = strlen(rearSide);
    size_t sizeOfRacer = sizeof(Racer);
->  Racer *nRacer = (Racer *)malloc(sizeOfRacer);
->  nRacer->graphic = (char *)malloc(lengthOfName);

    strncpy(nRacer->graphic, rearSide, lengthOfRearSide + 1);
    strcat(nRacer->graphic, name);
    sizeOfRear = strlen(nRacer->graphic);

    remain = MAX_CAR_LEN - sizeOfRear;
->  middleOfCar = (char *)malloc(remain);
    for (int x = 0; x < remain - 2; x++){
        middleOfCar[x] = '-';
    }
    strcat(middleOfCar, frontSide);
    strcat(nRacer->graphic, middleOfCar);
    nRacer->dist = 0;
    nRacer->row = position;
    return nRacer;
}
```

and here's the struct:

```
/// Rcr struct represents a racer position and display graphic.
///
typedef struct Rcr {

    /// current distance from starting line of the rear of the car
    ///
    int dist;

    /// vertical position of the racer, i.e. "racing lane"
    ///
    int row;

    /// graphic: the drawable text
    ///
    char *graphic;

} Racer;
```

Valgrind Errors:

```
ShaolinGOD@comp:~/Desktop/Threads$ valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --track-origins=yes ./pt-cruisers one two
==18972== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==18972== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==18972== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==18972== Command: ./pt-cruisers one two
==18972== 
==18972== Invalid write of size 1
==18972==    at 0x4C31644: __strncpy_sse2_unaligned (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18972==    by 0x401208: makeRacer (racer.c:52)
==18972==    by 0x400F4F: main (pt-cruisers.c:74)
==18972==  Address 0x5420093 is 0 bytes after a block of size 3 alloc'd
==18972==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18972==    by 0x4011DD: makeRacer (racer.c:50)
==18972==    by 0x400F4F: main (pt-cruisers.c:74)
==18972== 
==18972== Invalid read of size 1
==18972==    at 0x4C30C14: strcat (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18972==    by 0x40121F: makeRacer (racer.c:53)
==18972==    by 0x400F4F: main (pt-cruisers.c:74)
==18972==  Address 0x5420093 is 0 bytes after a block of size 3 alloc'd
==18972==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18972==    by 0x4011DD: makeRacer (racer.c:50)
==18972==    by 0x400F4F: main (pt-cruisers.c:74)
==18972== 
==18972== Invalid write of size 1
==18972==    at 0x4C30C30: strcat (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18972==    by 0x40121F: makeRacer (racer.c:53)
==18972==    by 0x400F4F: main (pt-cruisers.c:74)
==18972==  Address 0x5420093 is 0 bytes after a block of size 3 alloc'd
==18972==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18972==    by 0x4011DD: makeRacer (racer.c:50)
==18972==    by 0x400F4F: main (pt-cruisers.c:74)
==18972== 
==18972== Invalid write of size 1
==18972==    at 0x4C30C3F: strcat (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18972==    by 0x40121F: makeRacer (racer.c:53)
==18972==    by 0x400F4F: main (pt-cruisers.c:74)
==18972==  Address 0x5420096 is 3 bytes after a block of size 3 alloc'd
==18972==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18972==    by 0x4011DD: makeRacer (racer.c:50)
==18972==    by 0x400F4F: main (pt-cruisers.c:74)
==18972== 
==18972== Invalid read of size 1
==18972==    at 0x4C30F74: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18972==    by 0x40122F: makeRacer (racer.c:54)
==18972==    by 0x400F4F: main (pt-cruisers.c:74)
==18972==  Address 0x5420093 is 0 bytes after a block of size 3 alloc'd
==18972==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18972==    by 0x4011DD: makeRacer (racer.c:50)
==18972==    by 0x400F4F: main (pt-cruisers.c:74)
==18972== 
==18972== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==18972==    at 0x4C30C17: strcat (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18972==    by 0x401289: makeRacer (racer.c:61)
==18972==    by 0x400F4F: main (pt-cruisers.c:74)
==18972==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==18972==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18972==    by 0x40124A: makeRacer (racer.c:57)
==18972==    by 0x400F4F: main (pt-cruisers.c:74)
==18972== 
==18972== Invalid write of size 1
==18972==    at 0x4C30C3F: strcat (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18972==    by 0x401289: makeRacer (racer.c:61)
==18972==    by 0x400F4F: main (pt-cruisers.c:74)
==18972==  Address 0x54200e6 is 0 bytes after a block of size 6 alloc'd
==18972==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18972==    by 0x40124A: makeRacer (racer.c:57)
==18972==    by 0x400F4F: main (pt-cruisers.c:74)
==18972== 
==18972== Invalid read of size 1
==18972==    at 0x4C30C14: strcat (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18972==    by 0x4012A0: makeRacer (racer.c:62)
==18972==    by 0x400F4F: main (pt-cruisers.c:74)
==18972==  Address 0x5420093 is 0 bytes after a block of size 3 alloc'd
==18972==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18972==    by 0x4011DD: makeRacer (racer.c:50)
==18972==    by 0x400F4F: main (pt-cruisers.c:74)
==18972== 
==18972== Invalid write of size 1
==18972==    at 0x4C30C30: strcat (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18972==    by 0x4012A0: makeRacer (racer.c:62)
==18972==    by 0x400F4F: main (pt-cruisers.c:74)
==18972==  Address 0x5420096 is 3 bytes after a block of size 3 alloc'd
==18972==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18972==    by 0x4011DD: makeRacer (racer.c:50)
==18972==    by 0x400F4F: main (pt-cruisers.c:74)
==18972== 
==18972== Invalid read of size 1
==18972==    at 0x4C30C33: strcat (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18972==    by 0x4012A0: makeRacer (racer.c:62)
==18972==    by 0x400F4F: main (pt-cruisers.c:74)
==18972==  Address 0x54200e6 is 0 bytes after a block of size 6 alloc'd
==18972==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18972==    by 0x40124A: makeRacer (racer.c:57)
==18972==    by 0x400F4F: main (pt-cruisers.c:74)
==18972== 
==18972== Invalid write of size 1
==18972==    at 0x4C30C3F: strcat (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18972==    by 0x4012A0: makeRacer (racer.c:62)
==18972==    by 0x400F4F: main (pt-cruisers.c:74)
==18972==  Address 0x542009c is 9 bytes after a block of size 3 alloc'd
==18972==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18972==    by 0x4011DD: makeRacer (racer.c:50)
==18972==    by 0x400F4F: main (pt-cruisers.c:74)
==18972== 
0=two----o> Thread 3:
==18972== Invalid read of size 1
==18972==    at 0x401413: run (racer.c:116)
==18972==    by 0x4E416F9: start_thread (pthread_create.c:333)
==18972==  Address 0x5420183 is 0 bytes after a block of size 3 alloc'd
==18972==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18972==    by 0x4011DD: makeRacer (racer.c:50)
==18972==    by 0x400F4F: main (pt-cruisers.c:74)
==18972== 
                    ~X=one----o> Thread 2:
==18972== Invalid read of                                  ~X=two----o>
==18972==    at 0x4013C7: run (racer.c:107)
==18972== HEAP SUMMARY:F9: start_thread (pthread_create.c:333)
==18972==     in use at exit: 50 bytes in 6 blocksock of size 3 alloc'd
==18972==   total heap usage: 14 allocs, 8 frees, 3,288 bytes allocatedeck-amd64-linux.so)
==18972==    by 0x4011DD: makeRacer (racer.c:50)
==18972== Thread 1:00F4F: main (pt-cruisers.c:74)
==18972== 6 bytes in 2 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 1 of 3
==18972==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18972==    by 0x4011DD: makeRacer (racer.c:50)
==18972==    by 0x400F4F: main (pt-cruisers.c:74)
==18972== 
==18972== 12 bytes in 2 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 3
==18972==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18972==    by 0x40124A: makeRacer (racer.c:57)
==18972==    by 0x400F4F: main (pt-cruisers.c:74)
==18972== 
==18972== 38 (32 direct, 6 indirect) bytes in 2 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 3
==18972==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18972==    by 0x4011CC: makeRacer (racer.c:49)
==18972==    by 0x400F4F: main (pt-cruisers.c:74)
==18972== 
==18972== LEAK SUMMARY:
==18972==    definitely lost: 44 bytes in 4 blocks
==18972==    indirectly lost: 6 bytes in 2 blocks
==18972==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18972==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18972==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18972== 
==18972== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==18972== ERROR SUMMARY: 797 errors from 15 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
ShaolinGOD@comp:~/Desktop/Threads$
```

Comment: Since you are not telling *which* Valgrind errors you are getting, I would assume it doesn't like the lack of `free` calls...

Comment: @EugeneSh I'll update post with valgrind errors.

Comment: `size_t sizeOfRacer = sizeof(Racer);` what is the intention here?

Comment: @wildplasser it was the way I was taught to simplify the code more

Comment: `sizeof` never failed me. No need to wrap it into a variable. That will only introduce yet another unneeded identifier. Which will *not* simplify things.

Comment: Alright thanks, but would that really be the cause of my problems?

Comment: Yes: it could reduce the size of your source code by maybe 25 %. Fewer lines := fewer chances to make or hide errors. and `nRacer->graphic = (char *)malloc(lengthOfName);` should be `nRacer->graphic = malloc(1+ lengthOfName);` or use strdup(name)

Comment: What is the point of this exercise: `int lengthOfRearSide = strlen(rearSide); .... strncpy(nRacer->graphic, rearSide, lengthOfRearSide + 1);`?

Comment: ... and **never** use `strncpy()` until you read and understood its manual page.

Comment: Always check the result of Malloc against NULL because it returns null if it failed.  Also never ever ever ever, eva Eva Eva use strcat, use strncat to avoid memory overflow exploit

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you marked line 49, but the first valgrind error complains about line 52:

```
==18972== Invalid write of size 1
==18972==    at 0x4C31644: __strncpy_sse2_unaligned (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18972==    by 0x401208: makeRacer (racer.c:52)
==18972==    by 0x400F4F: main (pt-cruisers.c:74)
```

Which tells you that (by way of `strncpy`) you're writing to memory you don't own.

Line 52 is:

```
    strncpy(nRacer->graphic, rearSide, lengthOfRearSide + 1);
```

The memory for `nRacer->graphic` was allocated as:

```
    nRacer->graphic = (char *)malloc(lengthOfName);
```

So you allocated `lengthOfName` bytes, but you're writing `lengthOfRearSide + 1` bytes. Those are two completely different values: `lengthOfName` is 3 but `lengthOfRearSide + 1` is 4.

Comment: So I should be only assigning either lengthOfName or lengthOfRearSide?

Comment: @ShaolinGOD You should allocate enough memory for the strings you intend to store in your variables.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into `middleOfCar`. What happens to that?

You allocate it here:

```
middleOfCar = (char *)malloc(remain);
```

then you use it here:

```
middleOfCar[x] = '-';
    }
    strcat(middleOfCar, frontSide);
    strcat(nRacer->graphic, middleOfCar);
```

but what happens then?

Nothing more.... so you leak memory.

Maybe you need to `free` it before leaving the function

Comment: should I free anything else within that function? Freeing middleOfCar fixed the leak.

Comment: @ShaolinGOD - you must free everything that you don't carry a reference to.

Comment: So valgrind says I need to free nRacer->graphics, but I need to return nRacer... how would I free something I need to return?